# query database via foreignkey

Tags: django

I'm querying database:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = {'test_suites': TestSuite.objects.filter(user__user_id=self.request.user.id),
                'username': self.request.user)}
    return queryset
```

from this model field:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TestSuite(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    ...
```

`User` here is the auth User model from Django. I'm trying to filter data
from TestSuite by its user's id. Keep getting error:  `Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field`

**UPDATE:**

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = {'test_suites': TestSuite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user),
                'username': self.request.user}
    return queryset
```

Current traceback says:  `Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field.`

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: **Solution found here** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622261/filtering-data-from-db-by-logged-in-user#57622524

Answer (score 0):

probably because you have an extra ')' on your views:
`'username': self.request.user)}`

Comment: Well spotted but that wasn't it. Please see the update.

Comment: I might have to look at some tutorial as I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried: `'test_suites': TestSuite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)` ?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried because it made sense to me. When I use that code I get `no such column: frontend_testsuite.user_id`

Comment: I just don't understand why it doesn't work. Logically it makes sense:  Fetch data from the table by the field `user` (which is a foreignkey in this case) and get data of that particular user.

Comment: that error even doesn't make sense. I'm fetching data by the field `user` not `user_id`. Django's user model does have `id` field but I'm not querying that.