# filtering data from db by logged in user

Tags: django

I'm writing a queryset for data and result needs to be list of objects of that particular user. (logged in user)

This is what I've got so far:

```
class List(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qry =  House.objects.filter(user__user_id=self.request.user).all()
        return qry
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class House(models.Model):


    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    ...
```

I suspect that the very filtering condition is wrong because the traceback says `no such field user`

What can I try to solve this ?

Comment: use just `user_id` `(user_id=self.request.user)`

Comment: I recommend renaming `user_id` to `user` in the House model.

Comment: Your first suggestion gives me `no such column: user_id_id` in the traceback. Where am I filtering by `user_id_id` ...

Comment: Look accurately, not `user_id_id`, could you please edit the question with the updated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here:

```
qry =  House.objects.filter(user__user_id=self.request.user).all()
```

Is matching a user id, with a User object (i.e. not a user id). What you want is:

```
qry =  House.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).all()
```

(This in conjunction with the next change)

On Your `House` model, you're specifying `user_id`. This is confusing because what you are actually mapping to is the `User` object. Django will of course use the `id` field to do this, but you don't need to specify it. It is more normal to define your mapping to a foreign key as the name of the FK model (only in lower case, obviously, as it's a field name).

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I'm gonna  accept your answer because in most cases your solution would work but I need to also add to that the fact, that when I ran migrations I didn't run `makemigrations` first which I had to do first apparently. I thought you run `makemigrations` only when you need to commit changes to **an existing database** but in this case I had to add `default=1` to the `user` model field, then run `migrate`, then run `makemigrations` and then run `migrate` again to commit all changes. Now I'm getting desired output.

Comment: Lesson to learn here:  run `makemigrations` even if you think you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would also cause issues :) Though in this case makemigrations would have worked with your model, but you'd still have issues because you're trying to map an actual user to a user.id, and they are not the same thing. One problem at a time though :)